# передать значение переменной из одного ViewController'а в другой

Tags: swift

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно передать значение переменной из одного ViewController'а в другой?
Сейчас реализую следующим образом:
В обработчике нажатия ячейки

```
tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath):

                        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate! as! AppDelegate
                        let TaskData: TaskListTableViewController = TaskListTableViewController()
                        TaskData.catID = currentCell.categoryID!.text  // В этом месте пытаюсь передать данные

                        let initialViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("taskListTable")// as! UIViewController
                        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
                        appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

В контроллере TaskListTableViewController переменная объявлена:

    class TaskListTableViewController: UITableViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
        var catID: String?
//------------------------------
...
...
```

Но при выполнении catID возвращает nil

подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше использовать `segue`:

1 ПКМ от контроллера с которого переходим к контроллеру на который будем переходить:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2 Присваиваем идентификатор `segue`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3 Переопределяете `prepareForSegue` как Вам необходимо.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondVC //приводим `destinationViewController` к нужному нам `SecondVC`
    controller.s = "Woohoo" //s - строковая переменная, которой присваивем "Woohoo"
}
```

4 по нужному событию выполняете `performSegueWithIdentifier("SHOWVC", sender: self)`

Comment: segue не подойдет, так как в первом контроллере (TableViewController) при первом нажатии на ячейку отображаются обновленные данные этой же таблицы, а следующее нажатие должно отправлять на второй TableViewController, передавая данные нажатой ячейки. Используя segue  перевод во второй контроллер осуществлялся при первом же нажатии

Comment: @M.Sol Можно добавить флаг и при первом нажатии обновлять, а при втором отправлять на второй `VC`.

Comment: Можно пример реализации?

Comment: @M.Sol `if isCellFirstClick { //update data } else { //perform segue }`, где `isCellFirstClick` булевый флаг для ячейки `TableView`.